# Confusing RAM usage metrics on a Linux VPS

Tags: linux, memory, memory-usage

First of all, I know how Linux uses memory for disk caching (http://www.linuxatemyram.com/), but this seems to be something different.

First of all, I run htop. The total memory usage %s of all running processes equals just above 50%, and the same result is shown when I add up the real memory usage of all of the running processes. However, htop lists my memory usage as 1381/1536MB.

Looking around, I found that I should check free -m, to see if some of my memory was being used for disk caching. Alas, free just displays this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1536       1381        154          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1381        154
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I'm now very confused. Where is all this extra memory going? Did Linux "eat my RAM"?

**EDIT:** Sorry for causing some confusion, this VPS is running on OpenVZ.

Comment: I'm confused too - this is very, very odd. What distro? What are you running on this box?

Comment: What is your VPS provider?

Comment: Hello! I'm using CleverKite (cleverkite.com), and it seems as because they provide an OpenVZ-based VPS, there is no swap space provided or even allowed. I'm still not sure how this explains the disappearing RAM, though.

Comment: So, did you have more ram than 1536? Sorry, but I see the swap at 0 and I believed you refer at this.

Comment: My fault for not clarifying the question. When I add up the amount of physical memory used by each process, I find a number significantly less than 1536MB (my total amount of physical memory). However, my total memory usage is listed as near the total amount of physical memory (1381/1536MB). What I'm referring to is the disparity between these two numbers. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. You have 1381 used from 1536, did you expect to have 1536 used from 1536 ?

Comment: Actually, I expected a usage of around 600/1536, as that is what I got from adding up the physical memory usage of each of the running applications (as displayed in top).

Answer (score 3):

Your swap is disabled. If you really configured a swap partition then use

```
swapon -a
```

to enable it. If you forgot to create a swap partition then probably you should create it and activate it.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
```

Where 1024 is how much swap memory do you want. For a desktop system I recommend you to use double of your ram. Now you should "format" the swap file.

```
mkswap /swap
```

Now you should enable it:

```
swapon /swap
```

Now run free -m and you should see the free swap.

If you want swap to be enabled at boot time add the following line in /etc/fstab

```
/swap       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

If you still have free disk then configure a swap partition and rerun my instruction from mkswap and change /swap with the id of the partition.

Comment: Please note that there is nothing at all that motivates the rule that swap should be 2x ram on Linux. If you have a lot of ram you typically need less swap space, not more. For hibernation your Swap file needs to be at-least as large as the ram however.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: Note that if you follow this advice and your VM is using OpenVZ (which it smells like it is, from the lack of buffers) there's an excellent chance you **will** render your VM unbootable.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying that the VPS used OpenVZ in my original question - it has been edited to say so. I now realize that the VPS has no swap space allotted to it, but am still curious as to how this resolves the numbers. Could someone please clarify on that aspect?